# Creating multiple WiFi clients with a single wireless interface

Tags: wpa-supplicant, dhclient, iw

I am currently working on a project where I would like to be using a single TP-link wireless adapter and split it into multiple clients. 
What I've done so far;
I was able to create multiple virtual wlan0.1's using iw 
I've changed their MAC with macchanger... 
I was able to connect one of the interfaces to an AP using wpa_supplicant then dhclient for getting the IP.
I can run wpa_supplicant again with the secondary virtualized wifi interface but I can't get IP address. 
Any suggestions? 
Regards

Answer (score 2):

1. Is your WiFi adapter properly capable of multiple managed interfaces? Check the "valid interface combinations" line in `iw phy`.
2. Don't use a MAC changer, set the MAC when you add the interface (`iw dev <devname> interface add ... addr <mac-addr>`).
3. Multiple interfaces with different IP addresses are a pain in the neck to handle, because every program you use must be able to bind to a single interface, and even then there are surprises, so make sure you run both `dhclient` and `wpa_supplicant` only on the interface that needs it.

If it still doesn't work, please edit question with the exact commands you used (for all interfaces).